# How to Send Retrofit request .?

Tags: android, kotlin, postman

I an trying to send simple get request with text responce but I am facing Error.

Api is working properly in postman.
This is my curl request:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://yash-out.s3.amazonaws.com/cat3/vid55/hls_55.m3u8'
```

My Code:

```
object RestClient {
    val BASE_URL = "http://gamecorner.sd.zain.com/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null
    private const val TIME_OUT = 30
    val client: Retrofit?
        get() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            }
            return retrofit
        }
}
```

Api Call:

val apiService = RestClient.client!!.create(ApiInterfaces::class.java)
val call =
apiService.simpleJsonObjectResponseCall(url)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject?> {
override fun onResponse(
call: Call<JsonObject?>,
response: Response<JsonObject?>
) {
val obj = try {
Gson().fromJson(response.body() as JsonObject, SliderItem::class.java)
} catch (e: Exception) {
e.printStackTrace()
recreate()
return
}
val objArr = obj.data

```
            val vpAdapter = SliderAdaptor(this@MainActivity, objArr)
            viewPager2.adapter = vpAdapter
            viewPager2.clipToPadding = false
            viewPager2.clipChildren = false
            viewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = 2
            viewPager2.setCurrentItem(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2, true)

            binding.viewpager.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.clProgressView.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject?>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
```

Error:

```
A resource failed to call close.
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1409)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1391)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: I have used retrofit for many request in which I am getting Json Responce, Means I am well known with retrofit.

But I am Unable to get Responce form this API call.

Can you tell me what info you need to give the answer ?

Comment: can you post your log ? and better if you can post your code too

Comment: "Error" can mean anything - are you getting a compilation error? Are you getting a runtime exception? Is the response you receive simply not what you're expecting to see? You should also share the relevant bits of code - how can anyone tell you what you're doing wrong without actually seeing what you're doing?